# How to merge 4th field into 1 line instead of 2

Tags: awk, sed, cisco

This is `show version` output in Cisco APIC.

As you can see, it has weird output whereby the hostname of controller `AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC-0001` is seperated into 2 lines.

The same thing goes with other hostname as well.

**Actual `show version` output in Cisco APIC**

```
AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0001# show version 

 Role        Pod         Node        Name                      Version              
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------  -------------------- 
 controller  1           1           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_        3.2(4e)              
                                     APC-0001                                       
 controller  2           2           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_        3.2(4e)              
                                     APC-0002                                       
 controller  3           3           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_        3.2(4e)              
                                     APC-0003                                       
 spine       1           111         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_01  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     11                                             
 spine       1           112         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_01  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     12                                             
 spine       1           113         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_01  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     13                                             
 leaf        1           1101        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_11  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     01                                             
 leaf        1           1102        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_11  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     02                                             
 leaf        1           1103        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_11  n9000-13.2(4e)       
                                     03
```

I'm not sure if I can fix this in Cisco ACI itself, but I'm thinking probably this can be fixed with `sed` or `awk` script by saving the Cisco APIC `show version` output to `show_version.txt` file and then run the script on Linux box.

Unfortunately, I'm not really good in `sed` or `awk` scripting.

Is there a way to produce output like this?

```
[user@Linux ~]$ sed_or_awk_script_here show_version.txt

AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0001# show version 

 Role        Pod         Node        Name                        Version              
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------    -------------------- 
 controller  1           1           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0001        3.2(4e)
 controller  2           2           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0002        3.2(4e)                                   
 controller  3           3           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC_0003        3.2(4e)                                   
 spine       1           111         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0111  n9000-13.2(4e)                          
 spine       1           112         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0112  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 spine       1           113         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0113  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 leaf        1           1101        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1101  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 leaf        1           1102        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1102  n9000-13.2(4e)                            
 leaf        1           1103        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1103  n9000-13.2(4e)       

 [user@Linux ~]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` and assuming that the first line of `show version` is a blank line (making it three header lines):

```
awk '
  NR<4{ print; next }        # print 3 header lines
  NF>1{                      # if number of fields > 1
    sub($4, $4 "%s" )        # append `%s` to 4th field
    fmtstr=$0                # save modified line in `fmtstr`
    next                     # continue with next line
  }
  { printf fmtstr "\n", $1 } # print `fmtstr` with first field as argument
' show_version.txt
```

Output:

```
 Role        Pod         Node        Name                      Version
 ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------------  --------------------
 controller  1           1           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC-0001        3.2(4e)
 controller  2           2           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC-0002        3.2(4e)
 controller  3           3           AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_APC-0003        3.2(4e)
 spine       1           111         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0111  n9000-13.2(4e)
 spine       1           112         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0112  n9000-13.2(4e)
 spine       1           113         AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_SPN_0113  n9000-13.2(4e)
 leaf        1           1101        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1101  n9000-13.2(4e)
 leaf        1           1102        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1102  n9000-13.2(4e)
 leaf        1           1103        AB_CDE_FGH_IJ_ACI_LEF_1103  n9000-13.2(4e)
```

Comment: It works! I really appreciate the way you answer it with explanation for each parameter. It's very useful to understand how `awk` works